# Uninterpretable behavior with integer and decimal regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex that matches integers and decimals using python. It should be simple but it does not match the way I would understand it. Here is my super simple code:

```
import re
regnumber = "[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?"
re.findall(regnumber, "15")
```

This returns [''] which makes no sense because the above regex should force at least one digit from [0-9] and take the decimal and digits after as optional. What is going on?

Comment: You seem to accidentally have posted this twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77840568/uninterpretable-behavior-with-integer-and-decimal-regex

Answer (score 3):

It is returning the capturing groups. Make the group non-capturing with `?:`.

```py
regnumber = "[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?"
```

Comment: This is exactly correct. What does that mean capturing groups?

Comment: Noncapturing group: `(?:...)`, capuring group: any other `(...)`. Read the Python regex docs for more info.